# How to delete a sheet and insert the same sheet with the same name but prevent referencing errors in formula while doin so?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, vba

I have a value in cell **D8** of **Sheet2**.

Cell **A4** from **Sheet1** has a formula that contains the value of cell **D8** from **Sheet2**.

Now, when I delete the entire **Sheet2**, I get a referencing error in the formula from cell **A4** in **Sheet1**, which is fine.

But when I insert a new sheet with the same sheet name **Sheet2** with another new value in cell **D8**, my formula in cell **A4** of **Sheet1** still displays a referencing error.

How do I solve this?

For formulas within the same sheet, I can use **offset** function but I'm stuck when it comes to deleting and re-inserting sheets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indirect function in cell A4 of Sheet1 to hard code the address, like this
 `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!D8")`

Answer (score 1):

Either

- Just copy and paste the contents of the new *Sheet2* directly over the existing sheet.

or

- Rename *Sheet2* to a new name, for example *fred*
- Insert your new *Sheet2*
- Press *Ctrl* & *F* together..... *Replace* ....*find what: fred*, *replace with: Sheet2*
  [image]